# Можно ли из TFS'a взять 2 раза одно и тоже?

Tags: visual-studio, контроль-версий, tfs

Допустим, забрал я с TFS свежую версию кода и начал ее редактировать.

Потом, скажем, кто-то прибегает и говорит, что бы я срочно посмотрел почему версия, которая была до того, как я ее взял в работу(редактировал) падает на чем-то.

Так как у меня сейчас на руках недоделанная версия, то сделать я этого не могу=> я должен получить повторно версию из TFS, до своих правок, но что бы то, что я уже сделал не затерялось.

Т.е я должен, иметь как старую версию кода, до моих изменений, так и сохранить новую версию кода, что позже допилить и закомитить.

Как это можно сделать?

Не сильно разбираюсь в тонкостях TFS.

Наверное, еще один WorkSpace нужно завести и в него забрать версию до исправлений?

**UPD**

В комментариях предложили воспользоваться ветками и по описанию- это то, что нужно. Однако, как быть если не была создана ветка заранее?

Comment: В TFS нет веток? Между ними нельзя переключаться?

Comment: Есть, но не доводилось с ними работать=)

Comment: Ну так читайте мануал и работайте с ними, это стандартный функционал любой СКВ

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вроде, по описанию это то что нужно. Ответите на этот вопрос?

Comment: Нет, я не умею в TFS

Comment: Хоть ветки и есть, но , вроде, проблема останется, если я заранее отдельную ветку не сделаю.

Comment: Закоммитить и создать на месте

Comment: еще можно, наверное, извлечь в отдельную папку старую версию, пофиксить, закоммитить, и обновить текущую над которой работа идет.

Answer (score 5):

Для этого надо пользоваться Shelve.

Кто-то приходит и просит взять определенную версию кода для проверки.

- Вы делаете Shelve, и Ваши изменения сохраняются как черновики на TFS
  под именем, которое Вы дали.
- Теперь изменения можно в любой момент
  взять из TFS.
- Теперь вы можете смело удалять ваши локальные изменения
  и брать нужную версию.
- После нужных заказчику манипуляций можно взять
  последнюю версию кода и сделать UnShelve, все Ваши наработки
  вернутся.

Как приятный бонус количество Shelve не ограничено и их содержимое можно просматривать через web-интерфейс tfs.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fqKCTOARxQ0

Comment: Может быть вы и на этот вопрос сможете дать ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/905440/%D0%9C%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B2-tfs-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-workspace ?