# Можно ли в TFS выполнить миграцию WorkSpace?

Tags: visual-studio, контроль-версий, tfs

Т.е вот у меня была папка с решениями, которые я забирал с `TFS` на одном диске, а теперь хочу это перенести в другое место.

Как мне быть? Просто перенести данные в другое место, а потом замаунтить новое место `WorkSpace` и `TFS` все подхватит сам?